# UISearchBarの背景のViewを透明にしたい。

Tags: ios

イメージ図の黒いViewを透明にしたいと思ってます。

イメージは search.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

としたものです。わかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくおねがいします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

UISearchBarのSearch StyleをMinimalにすれば解決できるかと思います。

---

追記
コメント欄だと書ききれないのでこちらに追記します。

UISearchBarにある

・UISearchBarBackGround（UIImageViewのサブクラス）
・UISearchBarTextField（UITextFieldのサブクラス）

という2つのViewの設定をすれば実現できるかと思います。

UISearchBarのSubViewを追いかけていくと該当のViewが見つかるので、
適宜必要な部分をいじってみてください。

以下ソース

```
// UISearchBarのサブビューを取得
for (UIView *subview in self.SearchBar.subviews) {

    // UISearchBarのサブビューのサブビューを取得
    for(UIView *secondSubView in subview.subviews) {

        // 背景部分のViewを取得
        if ([secondSubView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

                // setImageでnilを渡す
                [(UIImageView *)secondSubView setImage:nil];

                // 任意の色を指定
                [secondSubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }

        // テキストフィールド部分を取得
        if ([secondSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField *)secondSubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];   
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: サンプル]

Comment: 加えてなのですが、角が丸い部分も透明になってしまいましたので、
その部分を白くしたいです。

Comment: @skd 
コメントの件について追記しました。